# Make only some rows bold in a Gtk.TreeView

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk3, pygobject

I want to display the status *read* or *unread* of a row by makeing the text (of a column in the row) **bold** or not.

The status of the row (or the data in the model) can be part of the model or somewhere else. I am flexible at this point.

How can I make the text of a specific cell bold depending on the underlying (dynamic) data, which is in this example the value `1`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class View(Gtk.TreeView):
    def __init__(self, model):
        Gtk.TreeView.__init__(self, model)
        col = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('Text',
                                 Gtk.CellRendererText(),
                                 text=0)
        self.append_column(col)
        # bold text
        # Gtk.CellRendererText(weight_set=True, weight=700),


class Model(Gtk.ListStore):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.ListStore.__init__(self, str, int)
        self.append(['foo 1', 0])
        self.append(['foo 2', 1])  # bold
        self.append(['foo 3', 0])
        self.append(['foo 4', 0])
        self.append(['foo 5', 1])  # bold

class Window(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.set_default_size(100, 200)

        # model & view
        self.model = Model()
        self.view = View(self.model)

        # layout
        self.layout = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(self.layout)
        self.layout.attach(self.view, 0, 0, 1, 2)

        self.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
        self.show_all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = Window()
    Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make the text bold?

Comment: @Azsgy This is part of the question. I don't want to make all rows bold - only some of them, depending on there data.

Comment: Great question, btw, took me a while to figure it out. Learned something too today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a short discussion with the Gtk maintainers, I've found that there is another, cleaner way to do this. Since both answers work, I've decided to put this as separate answer.

The problem with the other answer is that the `cell_data_func` gets called for every row. Over time, this will get really slow if you have many rows.

The solution here is to add another column to your model that you then bind to the relevant attribute(s).

Currently, you do the following:

```
col = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(
            'Text', renderer, text=0, weight_set=True)
```

This binds the `text` property of the `CellRenderer` to column 0 of your model.

Now, we can bind this to any other property too. For example, bind column 1 to the `weight` property:

```
col = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(
            'Text', renderer, text=0, weight=1, weight_set=True)
```

You can then set this column to different `Pango.Weight` values to change the weight of the text.

```
class Model(Gtk.ListStore):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.append(['foo 1', Pango.Weight.BOLD])
        self.append(['foo 2', Pango.Weight.BOOK])
        ...
```

If you want to set additional properties, you can also set the `markup` property (which parses the string as pango markup and allows you to change the font, color, etc of some parts of the text) and the `attributes` property, which you can use to set many style attributes at once with the [pango.AttrList](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Pango-1.0/classes/AttrList.html#Pango.AttrList) type.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. But this one (without cell_data_fund) I don't understand.

Comment: Got it. "Binding a property to a column" means: The values for the properties are stored in the model and read from there. Right?

Comment: @buhtz yep, precisely. That's the concept that's a bit hard to understand.

Answer (score 5):

As is often in Gtk, this is very very simple, just not very obvious. You really need to know where to look and read the related docs carefully.

```
class View(Gtk.TreeView):
    def __init__(self, model):
        Gtk.TreeView.__init__(self, model)
        renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        col = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(
            'Text', renderer, text=0, weight_set=True)
        col.set_cell_data_func(renderer, datafunc)
        self.append_column(col)
```

The first key is the `TreeViewColumn.set_cell_data_func` [method](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/TreeViewColumn.html#Gtk.TreeViewColumn.set_cell_data_func). This allows you to set an intercept function that you can use to modify the properties of the cell before it is rendered. Here's an example one I wrote which does what you want:

```
def datafunc(col, renderer, model, titer, data):
    val = model.get_value(titer, 1)

    if val:
        renderer.set_property("weight", 700)
```

As you can see, it receives the `TreeViewColumn`, `CellRenderer`, `TreeModel` and `TreeIter` involved, as well as custom data, which I've ommited.

The first step is to get the values of the current column. For that, we give the model the treeiter (which saves the "current row", kinda), and the column id we want (in this case the second column, `1`).

The rest is pretty simple, we use that value to decide if we need to set the "weight" property on the CellRenderer.

You used 700 here, but I'd recommend you to use `Pango.Weight.BOLD` instead for clarity. This requires `from gi.repository import Pango` of course.